# Why does msgrcv() return error with errno=7 (E2BIG)?

Tags: c, linux, ipc

I've built a small example that uses [msgsnd and msgrcv](http://linux.die.net/man/2/msgsnd), but sometimes `msgrcv()` returns 
`E2BIG`, and I'm not sure why that is, since I pass is the same `msgsz` to both `msgsnd()` and `msgrcv()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hand't realized that a named queue is persistent between runs, and `msgrcv()` was trying to read messages from the queue posted by **previous runs of my application**, which had been compiled with a larger `msgsz` at the time.